# Unity - How to calculate max distance (range) of a Projectile taking drag into account?

Tags: unity, physics, projectile-physics

I am able to calculate the projectile max distance, but it only works when there is no drag applied on the spherical projectile. I used the formula for range of a projectile as follows:-

```
void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.name == "bat")
    {
        initVel = ballRigidbody.velocity.magnitude;
        lineObject.transform.LookAt(transform);
        angle = Mathf.Abs(lineObject.transform.eulerAngles.x - 360);
        radianAngle = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle);
        maxDistance = (initVel * initVel * Mathf.Sin (2 * radianAngle))/ g;
    }  
}
```

This works well if there is no drag. But as I add drag, the range ends up being far away from where the projectile actually lands.

I looked up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Trajectory_of_a_projectile_with_air_resistance

but can't quite understand how to use it.

Here's a solution I tried

```
if(ballHeight > maxHeight)
{
    maxHeight = ballHeight;
}
else
{
    if(!flag)
    {
        maxHalfDistance = Vector3.Distance(ballFollow.transform.position, centerPoint.position);
        maxDistance = maxHalfDistance * Mathf.Clamp(maxHalfDistance, 1f, 1.75f);
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Basically calculating horizontal distance at max height and multiplying it a value between 1 and 1.75. ballFollow is horizontal position of ball and centerPoint is the launch position.
This works perfectly but there is a problem that actual range isn't calculated until the ball reaches its maxHeight.

So, how can range of a projectile be calculated taking air resistance in account?

Comment: Do you have any solution so far. i need help with that also. can you give me complete script?

Comment: This webpage explains the formulas clearer than Wikipedia: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/flteqs.html